# Problem using lapply in R with a function that uses constants in the global environment

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I'm trying to apply a function that takes some inputs from the global environment held in a vector (BASELINE_CLASSIFICATION_THRESHOLDS) to a dataframe using lapply. In essence, it transforms numbers to levels (Mild, Moderate, Severe, Extreme):

```
BASELINE_CLASSIFICATION_THRESHOLDS  <- c(0, 3.5, 6.5, 10.0000001)

value_to_classification <- function(x){

  if((x >= BASELINE_CLASSIFICATION_THRESHOLDS[1]) && (x < BASELINE_CLASSIFICATION_THRESHOLDS[2])){
    classification <- "Mild"
  } else if((x >= BASELINE_CLASSIFICATION_THRESHOLDS[2]) && (x < BASELINE_CLASSIFICATION_THRESHOLDS[3])){
    classification <- "Moderate"
  } else if((x >= BASELINE_CLASSIFICATION_THRESHOLDS[3]) && (x < round(BASELINE_CLASSIFICATION_THRESHOLDS[4]))){
    classification <- "Severe"
  } else {
    classification <- "Extreme"
  }
  return(classification)
}

df <- data.frame(x = runif(10, min = 0, max = 10),
                 y = runif(10, min = 0, max = 10),
                 z = runif(10, min = 0, max = 10))
```

But when I try to lapply value_to_classification to a column of x, I get an error:

```
lapply(df["x"], value_to_classification)
$x
[1] "Mild"

Warning messages:
1: In (x >= BASELINE_CLASSIFICATION_THRESHOLDS[1]) && (x < BASELINE_CLASSIFICATION_THRESHOLDS[2]) :
  'length(x) = 10 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
2: In (x >= BASELINE_CLASSIFICATION_THRESHOLDS[1]) && (x < BASELINE_CLASSIFICATION_THRESHOLDS[2]) :
  'length(x) = 10 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

On the other hand, if I write

```
lapply(df[["x"]], value_to_classification)
```

it works. What I eventually want to do is to write something like

```
df[c("x1", "x2")] <-  lapply(df[c("x", "y")], value_to_classification)
```

Some searching seems to suggest that my syntax is OK, but I'm clearly getting something wrong. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `value_to_classification` does not work for a vector. You can run `value_to_classification(c(1,2,3))` and it would only return one value (instead of 3).

One solution is to vectorize the function:

```
vectorized_value_to_classification <- Vectorize(value_to_classification)

df[c("x1", "x2")] <-  lapply(df[c("x", "y")], vectorized_value_to_classification)

df
          x        y         z       x1       x2
1  3.233599 5.612147 2.9525939     Mild Moderate
2  5.453014 3.659298 8.1642952 Moderate Moderate
3  7.104259 6.333049 7.1706136   Severe Moderate
4  4.199447 3.277607 8.9458447 Moderate     Mild
5  9.352140 7.135801 2.6721405   Severe   Severe
6  7.682951 1.358830 4.2102313   Severe     Mild
7  6.551999 9.986188 1.9995422   Severe   Severe
8  7.436272 9.260056 0.1093833   Severe   Severe
9  5.163593 7.689474 0.2999034 Moderate   Severe
10 7.500994 4.599129 8.5266752   Severe Moderate
```

Comment: Thank you. I was dimly aware of vectorization (min vs. pmin), but did not know that I could vectorize most any function.

Comment: @ThomasPhilips It is important to note that `Vectorize` is just a loop internally and therefore inefficient. You should rewrite your function. In your specific case, you should study `help("cut")`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Roland, I'll use `cut` instead